# Using SVN 1.4.6 with Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

The project I'm working on is configured with SVN 1.4.6. IDEA has integration problem with it when I try to update/commit, it says:

> Problems while loading file history: svn: E155021: This client is too
>   old to work with the working copy at C:\Users.......

On my machine, I'm using SVN tortoise:

> TortoiseSVN 1.8.0, Build 24401 - 64 Bit  | 
>   Subversion 1.8.0

How can I use the old svn working copy with IDEA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IDEA [doesn't support Subversion 1.8 working copies](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94942), you can checkout the project using IDEA built-in Subversion client to get the compatible working copy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! So if I donwgrade my tortoise to 1.6 or other, will it help?

Comment: Yes, it should help, but you will still need to perform a new checkout.

Comment: Yes! thanks, I didn't know that I could check out from IDEA directly!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the checkout with tutoise  then import the projet with intellij